# How to get input through a dropdownlist Combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to take user input from a `ComboBox` but don't let the user write anything into the `ComboBox`, rather he would select from the options given in that `ComboBox`. 
I have tried these 2 lines, but these are not working.

```
string var = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text; 
string var = Convert.ToString(ComboBox1.Text);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd imagine it's not working because you're getting compile errors? You can't define two variables with the same name within the same scope. Also, `var` is a keyword in C#, use a different name. Finally, the `.Text` property is already of type string, so the convert.tostring statement is unnecessary.

Comment: How do you fill this combo?

Comment: SelectedItem has no property named Text. This code will not compile.

Comment: You are looking for an autocomplete in other words ?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I imagine the OP is just showing two different lines that they tried.  Using `var` as a variable name does work, btw, it's just stupid to try it that way.

Comment: Thanks for your messages, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have items in your combobox, and want to get what the user selects. It also looks like you're trying to get the text of the selected value.

**To get selected item text:**

```
string val = ((ComboboxItem)Combobox1.SelectedItem).Text;
```

**To get selected index:**

```
int selectedIndex = Combobox1.SelectedIndex;
```

**Notable Problems with your code**

1. SelectedItem does not have a text property. It must be cast to a ComboboxItem.
2. "var" is a protected keyword. You can't use it as a variable name.
3. Converting a string to a string is redundant.

Comment: You should mark the answer as correct if it lead you to the solution. And upvote, as well. Glad I could help! Good luck with your software.

Comment: What is comboboxItem in 1st line?
where it is declared?

Comment: ComboBoxItem is not an object, but rather a type used to specify that the object should be converted into that type so you can call the "Text" method on it. See here for resource on casting: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_type_conversion.htm

Comment: it is giving me an error that The type or namespace name could not be found (Are u missing a using directive or assembly reference)